# FB Graph API - Filtering results by specific IDs?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am making a request to a specific node and edge using the graph API:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/NODE_ID/EDGE_NAME

Example:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/00000000000000/reports

which returns the results below:

```
"data": [
      {
         "id": "111111111111111",
         "name": "Report A"
      },
      {
         "id": "22222222222222",
         "name": "Report B"
      },
      {
         "id": "33333333333333",
         "name": "Report C"
      }
]
```

The above is literally returning a list of reports by id/name that exist under a specific company.

If I want to filter the results by specific reports, how can I go about doing this?

I tried variations such as the below, but they haven't worked and still return all reports:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/00000000000000/reports?ids=22222222222222

I know I can make the report ID as the node to access it directly:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/22222222222222/

But I want to view the properties of a subset of reports that belong to the company, so I was thinking I could build an array to do this.

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/00000000000000/reports?ids=22222222222222,33333333333333

Expected Result:

```
"data": [
      {
         "id": "111111111111111",
         "name": "Report A"
      },
      {
         "id": "22222222222222",
         "name": "Report B"
      },
      {
         "id": "33333333333333",
         "name": "Report C"
      }
]
```

This seems like it should work based on the below documentation, but it does not...
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api

Could it be because the edge I'm accessing isn't able to recognize these IDs for some reason...? I know it's hard to say without knowing what I'm doing, but I can't disclose fully as it's proprietary...

Any advice is appreciated.